# Read MySQL result set with multiple columns and spaces

Tags: mysql, bash

Pretend I have a MySQL table `test` that looks like:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |     value           |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | Hello World         |
| 2  | Foo Bar             |
| 3  | Goodbye Cruel World |
+----+---------------------+
```

And I execute the query `SELECT id, value FROM test`.
How would I assign each column to a variable in Bash using `read`?

`read -a` truncates everything after the first space in `value`:

```
mysql -D "jimmy" -NBe "SELECT id, value FROM test" | while read -a row;
do
    id="${row[0]}"
    value="${row[1]}"

    echo "$id : $value"
done;
```

and output looks like:

```
1 : Hello
2 : Foo
3 : Goodbye
```

but I need it to look like:

```
1 : Hello World
2 : Foo Bar
3 : Goodbye Cruel World
```

I'm aware there are args I could pass to MySQL to format the results in table format, but I need to parse each value in each row. This is just a simplified example of my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use individual fields in the [read loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601) instead of the array:

```
mysql -D "jimmy" -NBe "SELECT id, value FROM test" | while read -r id value;
do
    echo "$id : $value"
done
```

This will make sure that `id` will be read into the `id` field and everything else would be read into the `value` field - that's how `read` behaves when input has more fields than the number of variables being read into.  If there are more columns to be read, using a delimiter (such as `@`) that doesn't clash with actual data would help:

```
mysql -D "jimmy" -NBe "SELECT CONCAT(id, '@', value, '@', column3) FROM test" | while IFS='@' read -r id value column3;
do
    echo "$id : $value : $column3"
done
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TERMINATED BY ','' at line 1`. Does this only work when using an outfile?

Comment: Used `CONCAT` instead of `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` - that should work.  Looks like the latter works only when output is redirected to a file.

Comment: Wouldn't using `CONCAT` in this case now cause problems when `value` contains commas though?

Comment: Could you explain why this works? is it because there are only 2 variables and everything after the first delimiter is placed into the second?

Comment: also note that value is a keyword in mysql so you have to use escaped ` characters around it like:


SELECT CONCAT(id, '@', \\`value\\`, '@', column3) FROM test

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, also avoid piping a command to a while read loop if possible to avoid creating a subshell.

```
while read -r line; do
    id=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    value=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1=""; print $0}'|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'| sed 's/^[ \t]*//g')
    echo "ID: $id"
    echo "VALUE: $value"
done< <(mysql -D "jimmy" -NBe "SELECT id, value FROM test")
```

If you want to store all the id's and values in an array for later use, you can modify it to look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A -g arr

while read -r line; do
    id=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    value=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1=""; print $0}'|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'| sed 's/^[ \t]*//g')

    arr[$id]=$value
done< <(mysql -D "jimmy" -NBe "SELECT id, value FROM test")

for key in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$key: ${arr[$key]}"
done
```

Which gives you this output

```
dumbledore@ansible1a [OPS]:~/tmp/tmp > bash test.sh
1: Hello World
2: Foo Bar
3: Goodbye Cruel World
```